# Junit testing for HttpResponse Headers

Tags: java, cookies, junit, httpresponse

I got HttpResponse for post request, Now I need to check the cookies received with header name as 'set-cookie' with help of Junit.

How can I initialise HttpResponse with cookies and headers for Testing purpose??

```
response = clientInstance.execute(postRequest);
HeaderIterator iterator = response.headerIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Header header = (Header) iterator.next();

        if(header.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("set-cookie")) {
                    //grabbing cookies from response of name set-cookie
                    // In junit I mocked clientInstance.execute(postRequest) to mockResponse, but how to initialize the mockResponse with cookies
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you please show a little bit of code. E.g. what you have done so far.

Comment: code added @StefanBirkner

Comment: Are you using Apache HTTP Client?

Answer (score 0):

You should give in a mock of the response object. Then you can easily verify if all set header methods you have expected was called by your implementation.

One famouse mock framework you could use which has a really great junit integration is mockito, see:

http://site.mockito.org

Comment: Yeah, I know that but I am unable to create HttpResponse object with required cookies. How to create a response with cookies and headers? @snap